# How to make a post request using react redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have created a form with email, firstname, lastname details. Now I want to make a POST request to `localhost:5000/api/users` and want to store it in mongo database. How can I make use of redux ? I have implemented it using on reactjs only how can I make use of redux ? Note: I am using redux thunk.

Code:

login.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './login.css'

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      firstName:'',
      lastName:'',
      email:''
    }

    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)
    this.onSubmitHandler = this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this)
  }

  onChangeHandler(e){
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }

  onSubmitHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}>
          <label>
            FirstName:
            <input type="text" name="firstName" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
          </label>

          <label>
            LastName:
            <input type="text" name="lastName" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
          </label>

          <label>
            Email:
            <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.onChangeHandler} />
          </label>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

loginAction.js:

```
import { ADD_USER } from './types';
import axios from 'axios';

export const userLoginRequest = () => dispatch => {
    axios.post(`localhost:5000/api/users`)
    .then( userdata => 
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_USER,
            payload: userdata
        })
    )
    .catch( error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

loginReducer.js:

```
import { ADD_USER } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: ''
}


export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_USER:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand do I need to create 3 actions each one for firstname, lastname and email ? In that case what will be those 3 actions will it have 3 POST req in each of them ?

Comment: I suggest you read about Thunk and middleware in order to achieve asynchronous code in Redux.

Comment: @RonF I have read it now I need some help in organizing the code. I am not able to understand how to implement loginUser using react redux by making POST req to localhost:5000/api/users

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to have some insight about `redux` and `redux-thunk`.
For making network requests you need to use middleware like `redux-thunk` or `redux-saga`;

Here are very basic examples of `redux-thunk`

```
//example 1
function myThunkActionCreator(someValue) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch({type : "REQUEST_STARTED"});

        myAjaxLib.post("/someEndpoint", {data : someValue})
            .then(
                response => dispatch({type : "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED", payload : response}),
                error => dispatch({type : "REQUEST_FAILED", error : error})
            );    
    };
}

// example 2 for conditional dispatching based on state
const MAX_TODOS = 5;

function addTodosIfAllowed(todoText) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const state = getState();

        if(state.todos.length < MAX_TODOS) {
            dispatch({type : "ADD_TODO", text : todoText});
        }    
    }
}
```

**Update**

So the flow for posting the form data to the server using `redux-thunk` goes like so

1. When submit button is clicked and action gets dispatched let us suppose `SAVE_USER_TO_SERVER` and an object with all the user details (name, email etc) is passed to for eg `postUserThunkCreator()` (which is a thunk function like in examples above).
2. Then thunk makes a post request to the server and sends the data along with it. And on the server side it gets saved into the database and response is returned
3. Now `myAjaxLib.post("/someEndpoint", {data : someValue}).then()` in `.then()` function you can check for the response if successfull the dispatch another action for eg `SAVE_USER_TO_SERVER_SUCCESS` otherwise `SAVE_USER_TO_SERVER_FALIURE`;

*So as we can see that three actions are bieng dipatched in this work flow namely :
`SAVE_USER_TO_SERVER`

`SAVE_USER_TO_SERVER_SUCCESS`

`SAVE_USER_TO_SERVER_FALIURE`

So I hope its clear to you that you to create three action mentioned above.

**Your Question**
Do I need to create 3 actions each one for firstname, lastname and email ?

**Answer:** Not at all. Only three action mentioned above.

Comment: I want to ask you. Should I create 3 actions i.e for firstname, lastname, email ? And then reducer will have 3 action types am I right ? Can you add it in your answer.

Comment: ok let me edit the answser to add the redux flow for post request

Comment: If 3 actions are not required then how will I get email, firstname, lastname ? As the initialstate for all of them is "" So should I also create user object inisde initialstate ? I am not able to understand how will the reducer and actions will look like ?

Comment: Yes you should use `user = {}` in initialState and when the user is successfully saved `SAVE_USER_TO_SERVER_SUCCESS` update the user in store.

Comment: and when you will call action creator for eg `postUserThunkCreator()` you will pass the user info to actionCreator like so `postUserThunkCreator(this.state.firstName, this.state.lastName, etc)` in your case. Or if u take all fields in a single `user` object then simply `postUserThunkCreator(this.state.user)`

Comment: Can you please help here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106177/how-to-save-form-data-in-react-redux I have followed your steps as mentioned by you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182954/discussion-between-shivam-and-fun-joker).