# making a .post request using redux

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux, axios

I'm trying to allow user inputs through a form to add to an array of smurfs held in an API. Using the code below, when I input into the form, the data never makes it into my API. When I try to console.log the array the object I expect to hold the data retrieved upon user input--(newSmurf), it comes back empty. Can someone spot how to fix this?

the method:

```
export const addSmurf = (e, values) => dispatch => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({ type: ADD_SMURF })
    axios.post('http://localhost:3333/smurfs', values)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    })
};
```

the initial state and reducer:

```
const initialState = {
    smurfs: [],
    isFetching: false,
    error: '',
    newSmurf: []
}

const smurfReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_SMURF_START:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: true
            };
        case FETCH_SMURF_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFetching: false,
                smurfs: action.payload
            };
        case ADD_SMURF:
            return {
                ...state,
                newSmurf: [{
                    ...state.newSmurf,
                    name: action.payload,
                    age: action.payload,
                    height: action.payload
                }]
            }
        default:
            return state;
```

the component:

```
const Smurf = props => {

    const [newSmurf, setNewSmurf] = useState({ 
        name: "", 
        age: "",
        height: "",
    })

    // const handleSubmit = event => {
    //     event.preventDefault()
    //     axios.post('http://localhost:3333/smurfs', newSmurf)
    //     .then(res => console.log(res))
    //     .catch(err => console.log(err))
    //     setNewSmurf({
    //         name: "",
    //         age: "",
    //         height: "", 
    //     })
    // }

    const handleChanges = event => setNewSmurf({
        ...newSmurf,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
    console.log(newSmurf);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Smurfs</h1>
            {props.smurfs.map(smurf => (
                <div>
                    <p>{smurf.name}</p>
                    <p>{smurf.age}</p>
                    <p>{smurf.height}</p>
                    <br />
                </div>
            ))}
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={(handleChanges) => props.addSmurf(handleChanges)}>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="enter smurf name" onChange={handleChanges} />
                    <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="enter smurf age" onChange={handleChanges} />
                    <input type="text" name="height" placeholder="enter smurf height" onChange={handleChanges} />
                    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
                </form>
                <button onClick={() => props.getSmurfs()}>get smurfs</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        smurfs: state.smurfs,
        isFetching: state.isFetching,
        newSmurf: state.newSmurf,
        error: state.error
    }
}

export default connect (mapStateToProps, {getSmurfs, addSmurf})(Smurf);
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53100829/how-to-make-a-post-request-using-react-redux

Comment: Looks like when you call `props.addSmurf(handleChanges)` you're only giving it one argument, but the second argument is the `values` the you persist via the post request. Why aren't you passing it a second argument?

Comment: @Nick I wasn't giving it a second argument because of mere human error. That fixed it, thanks!